# Spring Boot application monitoring with Prometheus

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, health-monitoring, prometheus-alertmanager

We are working on the Monitoring and Alerting mechanism for Spring boot application hosted on the physical server. After some research, decided to go with

> Actuators  - To monitor application in every aspects
>
> Prometheus - Metric store
>
> Grafana    - For Dashboard visualization and alerting

Everything going well until Prometheus comes in to the picture. Am facing an issue in feeding the metrics to metric store.

**prometheus.yml**

`scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'spring-actuator'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:8080']`

**Prometheus server logs**

> level=info ts=2020-02-05T15:05:20.873Z caller=main.go:762 msg="Completed loading of configuration file" filename=prometheus.yml
>   level=info ts=2020-02-05T15:05:20.873Z caller=main.go:617 msg="Server is ready to receive web requests."

Prometheus Dashboard showing **no data to display**.

Side Note, Spring Boot Services are up and it returning data when localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus is being hit. Disabled the sensitivity of Actuator endpoints.

actuator/prometheus endpoint result:

[image: Spring Boot Micrometer Resp]

Comment: is grafana actually running on the same host? Running in docker doesn't count as localhost in a docker image will keep the request within the instance.

Comment: Spring boot app, Prometheus, Grafana are all running on my local machine. No docker involved here

Comment: could you add the whole output in txt? and second question - are you actually querying any Prometheus metrics in the dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

There is too little info to be able to answer this question, but whenever I saw the **no data to display** it had to do with metrics inconsistency, incorrectly set up gauges or bad queries.

You need to look for error/potential problems in your actuator/prometheus endpoint, there might be some information about this.

I will be glad to help if you submit the endpoint output.

Comment: Thanks, Attached the actuator/prometheus endpoint out. Please check